# Is it ok to require() the same file multiple times?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a server.js which looks like:

```
var app1 = require('./app1.js');
app1.start();

var app2 = require('./app2.js');
app2.start();
```

Now I have a common.js that is used in in both app1.js and app2.js.

So in app1.js I have:

```
var common = require('./common.js');
```

and in app2.js I have:

```
var common = require('./common.js');
```

I'm wondering if this is ok to do this. Does node use the same reference in both these situations, or is it duplicated?

Comment: Yes, that’s fine, and they’ll be the same object (though it’s not generally good design to count on that last part).

Comment: @Ryan Why should I not count on that part? If that was not the behavior, then most of the internet would come crashing down.

Comment: Node caches requires, so it really doesn't matter how many times you require it

Comment: Related answer from just a few hours ago: [Using inline require called multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46045675/using-inline-require/46045734#46045734)

Comment: @torazaburo: If you were relying on it, it would mean you were relying on singletons/stateful modules, which tend to be bad ideas.

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**, it is absolutely fine to do this. `require()` essentially includes the contents of the target page on the current page. If you need to use the modules on multiple pages, you will need to use `require()` on each page.

`var common = require('./common.js')` will result in the variable `common` having the exact same structure as whatever is returned by `module.exports` in `common.js`. In fact, they'll be the exact same object.

There's some great documentation regarding this at **[SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-module-exports-exports-node-js/)**.

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 0):

It is okay. However, they do use the same references which is cached by node. So try not to mutate the required files by mutating object properties, otherwise you may encounter some unexpected behavior.