# Is it possible to use "require" on the fly multiple times in the same file?

Tags: typescript, require

I would like to know if it's possible to use `require` on the fly two times **in the same file**.

Between the first and the second time, my imported file was updated, and I want to read the content of the updated file.

To simplify the problem, I will simply delete the file between the two `require` instead of updating it.

```
fs.removeSync(/path/to/my/file);
const final = require(/path/to/my/file);
// => crash : cannot find module
```

The crash is normal (I removed the file).

Now, if I require the file before removing it, there is no crash.

```
const initial = require(/path/to/my/file);
fs.removeSync(/path/to/my/file);
const final = require(/path/to/my/file);
// => No crash !!!
```

So, I suppose that `require` is not really called a second time, but I'm not sure of it.

I don't find how to read a first time the content of the file, update it and later read it again in the same file.

Any help will be welcome !

PS:
I red this post [Is it ok to require() the same file multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46046642/is-it-ok-to-require-the-same-file-multiple-times) , but it's not what I want : I want to require two times in the **same** file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why does the second require not crash?**

This is because every require [caches](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) the loaded files. You would have to delete the cache before requiring the updated file. Which can be done with the [delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete) since the cache is a simple object `delete require.cache[require.resolve('/path/to/my/file')]`.

I dont think thats a good idea though. Why are you not using [fs.readFile](https://nodejs.dev/learn/reading-files-with-nodejs) for that?

Comment: Yes, excellent ! I forgot that `require` caches the loaded files. You saved my life ! (or just my day, maybe... ;) )

Comment: Hi, sorry, I'm a new contributor, and I didn't know how to do. I think that it's ok now. So, don't forget to vote +1 for my question ! :)